# Slimerjs takes a snapshot of only the visible area

Tags: facebook, screenshot, slimerjs

I am doing a screenshot using slimerjs, and if you specify a width smaller than the minimum width of the page - that cuts to the visible region.

This happens only on Facebook.

https://github.com/Samael500/save_screenshot_test/blob/32af68387072a690ebce18b29c973330ac2497b4/img/slimerjs/www.facebook.com-240px.png

But on other sites (such as Google) render the all page.

https://github.com/Samael500/save_screenshot_test/blob/32af68387072a690ebce18b29c973330ac2497b4/img/slimerjs/google.com-240px.png

I make a screenshot with this script

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0';
    page.open('https://www.facebook.com/', function (status) {
        page.viewportSize = { width:240, height:768 };
        page.render('img.png');
        page.close();
        slimer.exit();
    });
```

And call it that way
`$ ./slimerjs slimer_screen.js --ssl-protocol=any`

How to get a snapshot of the facebook page full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Before opening the page, you must specify the native resolution for the browser.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width:1024, height:768 };
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0';
page.open('https://www.facebook.com/', function (status) {
    page.viewportSize = { width:240, height:768 };
    page.render('img.png');
    page.close();
 slimer.exit();
});
```

So the solution in line `page.viewportSize = { width:1024, height:768 };`

Comment: Is the second `viewPortSize()` (just before `render()`) intentional, or no longer needed?

Comment: It is necessary to set the desired width for the render. If the site allows to resize to the required width. example is https://github.com/Samael500/save_screenshot_test/blob/master/img/slimerjs/wbtech.pro-240px.png